# Limited combination problem

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

### Problem:

Imagine you have N balls, that you want to put into M boxes. How many ways are there to put N balls into M boxes, if every box can store no more than K balls.
 For convinience, I named the number of ways to put N balls into M boxes as "W"

You can't leave any box empty.
Boxes are labeled, balls are not.
There is no difference in which order you put balls.

### What I found:

I started by simply counting the number of these ways for boxes with K=2.
[K=2 results diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcseR.jpg)
W-s seem to form a Pascal's triangle, so I continued for K=3
[K=3 results diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXR4X.jpg)
With K=3 it seems that W-s form a variation of Pascal's triangle, but instead of summing up 2 numbers above, you sum up 3.[This is how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19qhs.jpg)
The same goes for K=4
[K=4 results diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0wPG.jpg)

### Question:

I can't find a rigorous proof, that algorithm with these Pascal triangles is true. Please help(

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Associated_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: In balls-and-boxes problems you must clarify which objects are considered distinct if any.  Are all the balls labeled?  Are all the balls indistinguishable from one another?  Are all the boxes labeled?  Are all the boxes indistinguishable from one another?

Comment: and (in addition to what specified by *JMoraitz*), what do you exactly mean by *put* ? because to "throw" undistinguishable balls one after the other is not the same as "laying" (pouring) the balls

Comment: Start by putting one ball in each box and then analyzing remainder.  It is simpler if all balls are identical and you are concerned only about counts.